# How to convert WMA to VORBIS or OPUS?

Tags: audio, conversion, media, ogg, codec

My girlfriend accidently bought an audio book on the internet and she saved it on my hard disk in windows media audio format (`.wma`) and now she asks me how to listen to it. I'm a bit puzzled this format still survived.

I'm on ArchLinux, kernel `4.2.1-1-ARCH`. My first idea was simply trying to read it with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) as it usually is a general problem solver for audio files and comes with a couple of codecs. But it didn't work.

Second idea was converting, I usually use [Audacity](http://audacityteam.org/) for quick format swaps, but after several attempts of exporting to `ogg/vorbis` or `ogg/opus` I noticed Audacity already failed to read the proprietary file format.

I looked up the [codecs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Codecs) section on arch wiki but it does not contain any hints for WMA. How to proceed?

How to convert `audio/x-ms-wma` to `audio/ogg`, `audio/vorbis`, or `audio/opus` format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *community* repo, there's a package called **audio-convert**.
Install it with `pacman -S audio-convert` and it should do the trick.

Remember to also install the optional packages: **mplayer** (needed for wma support) and **vorbis-tools** (for ogg).

Comment: how? `audio-convert` creates a 245kB mp3 file from a 280MB wma file. the result sounds like r2-d2. it does not offer ogg formats.

Comment: Installed `mplayer` and `vorbis-tools`? They're the optional packages you need. pacman tells you to do it after installing audio-convert.

Comment: good hint, maybe you want to update your answer with some more details. meanwhile i figured the wma file is drm protected. i guess i was digging in the wrong direction. thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

`audio-convert` has not been updated since 2005. At this point it makes more sense to just use `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i foo.wma -o foo.opus
```

The default is 96 Kbps VBR. That's way more than enough for an audiobook: 96 K is good enough for most stereo music; you can go down to `-b:a 24k` for mono voice and [almost not tell the difference](https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Opus#Speech_encoding_quality).

---

Regarding the Windows Media DRM stuff, you will need to strip it on Windows first with the drmdbg / FairUse4WM stuff. I've not seen anything about doing this removal on Wine: Windows Media Player runs for sure, but no idea about the debuggers that hook to it and extract the key.